# Apply styles for each shape

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application with 2 coubes one above another. I tried to rotate each coube using drag action with mouse cursor. Unfortunattely i didn't manage and rotate  style does not work properly.

```js
export default function App() {
  const myref = useRef(data.map(() => createRef()));
  const [offSet, setOffset] = React.useState(0);
  const [startX, setStartX] = useState(null);

  const rotate = e => {
    console.log("ev");
    setStartX(e.pageX - offSet);
  };

  const stopRotate = () => {
    setStartX(null);
  };

  const detectDirection = e => {
    if (startX) {
      setOffset(e.pageX - startX);
      console.log(offSet);
      myref.current.map(
        ref => (ref.current.style.transform = `rotateY(${offSet}deg)`)
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="wrapper">
        {data.map((i, k) => {
          return (
            <div
              ref={myref.current[k]}
              onMouseOut={stopRotate}
              onMouseDown={rotate}
              onMouseMove={detectDirection}
              className={`box box-nr-${i.id}`}
              key={k}
            >
              {i.title}
              <div className="side left" />
              <div className="side right" />
              <div className="side front" />
              <div className="side back" />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How to make rotating each shape using drag action? Now when i try to rotate i rotate both, plus the action does not work ok. I want, depending by the shape that you drag, to rotate it horizontaly, but not both. How to do this?

I want to do, something like this, but only horizontaly rotating: https://codepen.io/Ra1ny/pen/LdwOGG?editors=1111

Comment: Your data.js file is empty in your codesandbox :(

Comment: @HermitCrab, i fixed. Now it is working?

Comment: @HermitCrab, do you know the solution?

Comment: OK, it's working now, I will write an answer

Comment: @HermitCrab, thank you, it will be great

Answer (score 0):

In your App component, you only have one set of parameters for all of your cubes:

```
const [offSet, setOffset] = React.useState(0);
const [startX, setStartX] = useState(null);
```

So both cubes will rotate at the same time because they share the same rotation parameters.

You should create a separate Cube component, and move:

```
const [offSet, setOffset] = React.useState(0);
const [startX, setStartX] = useState(null);
```

inside the Cube component, so that each cube has its own rotation parameter. You need to also move `rotate`, `stopRotate` and `detectDirection` inside this new Cube component.

Then in your App render function, you will render the Cube using map:

```
{data.map((i, k) => {
          return (
            <Cube
              key={k}
            >
```

Comment: how to set `rotate, stopRotate and detectDirection` for each cube?

Comment: Create a new Cube component and put these functions inside this Cube component, so that each Cube is completely autonomous

Comment: And in this new Cube component, put your useState and a single ref (no more need for an array of ref)

Comment: but what if i will have 20 cubes. I have to create 20 new Components?

Comment: No you just create one Cube component, and you App can render as many as you want (like in the last code part of my answer)

Comment: @HermitCrand, i don't understand actually how to create this component, or i render each cube in map() function. I should create a generic component and to render inside map(), and for that component i should pass props all my functions?

Comment: I have added a new reply with the code for a Cube component and how to use it inside your App

Comment: it is ok, but i can't get why when i rotate the cube, it changes his position, i mean it does not has  vertical position, like it  is rotating  around something. Do you know why?

Comment: Make a new codesandbox with the Cube component and I will have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for your Cube component (untested):

```
function Cube(props) {
    const myref = useRef();
    const [offSet, setOffset] = React.useState(0);
    const [startX, setStartX] = useState(null);

    const rotate = e => {
        console.log("ev");
        setStartX(e.pageX - offSet);
    };

    const stopRotate = () => {
        setStartX(null);
    };

    const detectDirection = e => {
        if (startX) {
            setOffset(e.pageX - startX);
            console.log(offSet);
            myref.current.style.transform = `rotateY(${offSet}deg)`;
        }
    };

    return (
        <div
            ref={myref}
            onMouseOut={stopRotate}
            onMouseDown={rotate}
            onMouseMove={detectDirection}
            className={`box box-nr-${props.i.id}`}
            key={k}
        >
            {props.i.title}
            <div className="side left" />
            <div className="side right" />
            <div className="side front" />
            <div className="side back" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then in your App render:

```
<div className="App">
  <div className="wrapper">
    {data.map((i, k) => {
      return (
           <Cube key={k} i={i} />
       );
    })}
  </div>
</div>
```